# Select a list of unique element from a node list using XPATH

Tags: xml, dom, xpath

Is it possible in XPATH to select a list of unique element from a node where there are many of the same?

```
<Deserts>
 <Desert Code="C1">Popsicle<Desert>
 <Desert Code="H2">Ice Cream<Desert>
 <Desert Code="C1">Popsicle<Desert>
 <Desert Code="T1">Cheese Cake<Desert>
</Deserts>
```

In this example I want the resulting list to have only 3 nodes (Popsicle / Ice Cream / Cheese Cake).

How can I select such a list with Xpath?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a shorter, XPath 2.0 solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following xpath:

```
/Deserts/Desert[not(@Code=preceding-sibling::Desert/@Code)]
```

It will return distinct deserts by checking the Desert Code attribute.

Answer (score 2):

**XPath 2.0 solution**:

```
(/*/*/@Code)[index-of(/*/*/@Code,.)[1]]
```

Comment: Thanks @Dimitre-novatchev! I will keep this info close. I'm developing on VBA/Dom so I have to use Xpath 1.0.